# Create Uncompressed Zip in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have a question according to the ZipArchive Library in System.IO.Compression.
I want to create an uncompressed .zip file. My code so far looks like this:

```
//Creates a "Deflate"-Mode file in the created zip.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(zippath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var demoFile = zip.CreateEntry("foo0.txt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);  //NoCompression does not seem to have an impact
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(demoFile.Open()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write("Bar!");
    }
}
```

Thats creating me a zip file, where the file in it was written in "DEFLATE" Mode not in STORE. How can I fix this. My thought was, my problem would be solved by using the CompressionLevel.NoCompression.

Also writing the file to the filesystem and zipping the directory is not an option, because i want to create a zipfile with potentially hundred of thousands small files. Furthermore just using GZipStream is not an option, because I want to create a directory structure in the .zip file.

I checked the mode with 7-zip:

[(screenshot from 7-zip)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvIC0.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want it uncompressed.

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran your code and looked at the archived files. 7-Zip does indeed say the method used was DEFLATE but if you look at the packed size, you'll notice that 0% compression is reported per file. I tried with a large file twice, the first time uncompressed and the second time compressed and the difference is apparent.

Comment: I have to create those files, because thats kind of a format... (fyi https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/issues/853). So the files have to be uncompressed. If I would have the choice it wouldn't be a problem ...but it's the specification i have to fullfill...

Comment: In the [MSDN articles remark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel.aspx#Remarks), it says that "These values do not correspond to specific compression levels". 
So this API will not guarantee that you can create ZipFile of what you want.

Comment: The tools from [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) apparently use DEFLATE as only compression _method_, the API doesn't support the STORE method. The compression _level_ is just forwarded as a hint to the actual compression algorithm.

Comment: thanks kunif and amain! Can you recommend any alternatives? I've tried dotnetzip, but for my usecase it seems far to slow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for whatever reason you are required to add contents to a ZIP file with its compression method explicitly set to *STORE* (no compression), you will need to use some third party library.

The .NET classes in `System.IO.Compression` use *DEFLATE* by default. There is no apparent way to change this and use another compression method or algorithm.
Providing `CompressionLevel.NoCompression` just tells the *DEFLATE* algorithm to work with the lowest compression rate<sup>1</sup>. In terms of file size, this will probably give you roughly the same end result, anyway.

Third party libraries supporting the method *STORE* include:

- [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)
  (see [supported formats](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/FORMATS.md))
- [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib)
  (see [compression methods](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.CompressionMethod.html))
- [DotNetZip](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip)

---

<sup>1</sup> which should be... no compression. See DEFLATE's [non-compressed blocks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951#page-11)

Comment: The first two (SharpCompress and SharpZipLib) work also in .NET core environment

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who happens to see this topic later on, I would highly recommend the ZipStorer class by Jaime Olivares:

https://github.com/jaime-olivares/zipstorer

It's easy to add this code to a C# project (not a DLL), and it's easy to add files using 'store' instead of 'deflate'.